# Setup vsftpd server so that I can access the web root

Tags: linux, ftp, centos5

Probably getting fed up with the amount I have posted today lol.

I am trying to find a tutorial which will show me how to correctly install and setup vsftpd on centos 5.5... This is probably one of the most simplist of tasks, however I am still a newbie and just trying to setup a server on our local network which will act as an intranet.

I have everything else installed and working... Anonymous ftp works and I can get to the /var/www/html/ directory, however I just can't seem to get user accounts to work.

```
*** CuteFTP 8.3 - build Aug 25 2008 ***

STATUS:>    [06/08/2010 15:04:49] Getting listing ""...
STATUS:>    [06/08/2010 15:04:49] Connecting to FTP server... 192.168.1.136:21 (ip = 192.168.1.136)...
STATUS:>    [06/08/2010 15:04:49] Socket connected. Waiting for welcome message...
        [06/08/2010 15:04:49] 220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
STATUS:>    [06/08/2010 15:04:49] Connected. Authenticating...
COMMAND:>   [06/08/2010 15:04:49] USER j0nR
        [06/08/2010 15:04:49] 331 Please specify the password.
COMMAND:>   [06/08/2010 15:04:49] PASS *****
        [06/08/2010 15:04:52] 530 Login incorrect.
ERROR:>     [06/08/2010 15:04:52] Not logged in.
STATUS:>    [06/08/2010 15:04:54] Connection closed.
```

I am about ready to smack my head on the table!

I am not sure I have even setup the ftp users correctly, any further information you require please do let me know but you will have to talk to me like the newbie that I am.

Thanks in advance, and happy friday :)

---

### **EDIT**

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
#anon_root=/var/www/html/
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/html/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

---

**That is my vsftpd.conf file.**

Comment: Your config entry gave me new ideas to set user directory, I was looking for a way to set access to webroot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more useful to paste your vsftpd config, but check the following:

- The username is allowed to login to FTP. If the username is in /etc/vsftpd/user_list then you need to ensure that, in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf, userlist_enable=YES and userlist_deny=NO. If the username is not present then you need to make sure that, if userlist_enable=YES then userlist_deny=NO or is not present.
- Check the shell and home directory in the passwd file. Type vipw and check that the shell is not /bin/false (change it to /sbin/nologin if it is) - I'm not sure why this is an issue
  but I've seen it cause problems before. Next, set the home directory to wherever you want the user to login to. Not essential, but more secure.
- Ensure that the user has access to the directory. Do `su j0nR -` and then try to cd into their home directory. If it works, it's probably a password issue. Type `passwd j0nR` and set it to what you think it should be.

Good luck.

Comment: I updated with my vsftpd.conf file. :)

Comment: Still keep getting COMMAND:> [06/08/2010 15:47:32] USER j0nR
  [06/08/2010 15:47:32] 530 Permission denied.

Comment: Updated the conf file as per your ideas, and still not working... :(

Comment: It's refusing to allow the user to login. Try using ftp from the command line on the server, so:
`ftp localhost` It will ask for the username, enter j0nR. If it then denies entry before asking for the password it's an issue with the userlist. Otherwise it's either an issue with the password or with the user not being able to access their home directory.

Comment: Ok, I can login and it then fails after entering the password... I have tried countless times to change the password and I have setup multiple accounts and still not working... I am going to try and reinstall it all over again and see what happens... It's driving me nuts... I threw a follow your way on twitter for all the help you have given me today lol. :)

Comment: Did you try the `su j0nR -` and try to cd to the home directory? Thanks for the follow :)

Comment: Sure, I did this as currently it's within the home directory... Then that took be straight in. Still no luck with the ftp... I reverted back to the standard .conf now and tried that with modification and no luck still. I think I am about ready to give up... In about 1 hours time I have to leave the office for the weekend and don't have remote access lol... Will have to wait until Monday I guess :( Cheers for the help fella :)

Comment: is selinux enforcing? Type `getenforce` and see what it says.

Comment: I have already disabled that mate... As you mentioned that in my other question about ports :)

Comment: Returns Disabled as I thought

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/shells` to ensure that the shell your user account is set to is included there.  If it isn't, the account can't use ftp, period.  Usually I specify `/bin/false` for ftp-permitted non-interactive-shell users, and `/sbin/nologin` for users which I don't want to have a shell OR ftp access.

If you have `userlist_enable=yes`, then you need a `userlist_file=/etc/ftpusers` (or some other file).  Add the users you want to permit access to that file (unless you have `userlist_deny=yes` as well, in which case users will be permitted if they are not in that file).

Answer (score 0):

edit

```
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

and check if chroot_local_user=YES is there..if it's not there , add it..it makes sure that they user that we are gonna create will be able to access only the directory assigned to him . and also local_enable=YES

**adding user**

```
useradd -d /path/to/your/directory jonraw
```

this will add a  user called jonraw.
then set password

```
passwd jonraw
```

there are many more things to take care of  like changing permissions of the directory , disabling ssh login for the user etc..
you can read more options about vsftpd in the below url.
 http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: Weirdly, I still have no joy with that. User / Password set fine with no errors and still getting the above errors. :( Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: did you restart vsftpd after changing /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf ?? 

/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart

or

service vsftpd restart

Comment: I used service vsftpd restart, I always restart no matter what changes I make just to be safe. Please bare in mind that this on a local network, could this be the cause of my problems?